# go-git equivalent to "git push --all <remote>"

Tags: git, go, go-git

Having trouble finding a way to push all branches to a remote using `go-git` without iterating all branches. I've looked at the `PushOptions` definition, and I'm not seeing an option that correlates to `git push --all <remote>`. Has anyone accomplished this?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. You'd iterate all references yourself and create a refspec for each and add them to [`PushOptions.RefSpecs`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-git/go-git@v4.7.0+incompatible?tab=doc#PushOptions).